# Django-import-export. Export selected records only?

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using the great [django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) addition.

We standard have 2 options import and export. I would like to have an extra option to export selected records only. Would be a nice addition. How can I achieve this?

I use the standard configuration in the Django admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

[image]

To do this, simply declare an Admin instance which inherits from `ExportActionModelAdmin`:

```py
class CategoryAdmin(ExportActionModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then register this Admin:

```py
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

Note that the above example refers specifically to the [Example app](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app), you'll have to modify to refer to your own Model instances.

Comment: Works! To prevent confusion 'Category' is a sample name. Replace this with the model name where you want to see the action. In my case Shift. I already had a ShiftAdmin so I only had to add 'ExportActionModelAdmin' the admin EG: 
class ShiftAdmin(ExportActionModelAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):
NB:  'pass' is only needed if there is no other code in the admin